# Android Share location like whatsapp

Tags: android, geolocation

I have searched for this more than 4 hours but did not find anything useful, I need to add to my android app the ability for the user to send location, just like whatsapp or something similar.

thanks

Comment: You mean, send information about user location to another user, who is using the app?

Comment: The code you want are able to find every where, just get your path correctly.

Comment: @okset yes correct

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601295/how-can-you-share-location-same-like-whatsapp-in-android-with-chooser-dialog

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example Firebase Database to store the user locations on remote server.

The flow can be like this:

- get the user location
- send your location via FirebaseDatabase
- get the location of the another user/users via FirebaseDatabase

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/