# how can you share location same like whatsapp in android with chooser dialog?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-maps-api-3, whatsapp, android-intent-chooser

I want ***"share location"*** functionality same like ***whatsapp*** in my current application.
[image: Here is a chooser dialog]

[image: Here is a share location screen]

[image: After selecting your location it displays like this]

Now to open chooser dialog i used below mentioned code.

```
public static void showFileChooser(Activity activity, Fragment fragment, boolean isAllowMultiple) {
        try {

            File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "demo");
            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "i" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file); // save to the private variable

            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
            captureIntent.putExtra("capturedimageuri", mCapturedImageURI.toString());

            // Intent for Audio Recording
            final Intent audioRecordIntent = new Intent();
            audioRecordIntent.setAction(IxxxConstants.ACTION_AUDIO_RECORD);

            final Intent videoRecordIntent = new Intent();
            videoRecordIntent.setAction(IxxxConstants.ACTION_VIDEO_RECORD);

            // Use the GET_CONTENT intent from the utility class
            Intent target = com.xxx.xxx.filechooser.FileUtils.createGetContentIntent();
            if (isAllowMultiple) {
                target.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            }
            // Create the chooser Intent


            if (activity != null) {
                Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(
                        target, activity.getString(R.string.chooser_title));

                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{captureIntent, audioRecordIntent, videoRecordIntent});
                activity.startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_ANNOTATION_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(
                        target, fragment.getString(R.string.chooser_title));

                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{captureIntent, audioRecordIntent, videoRecordIntent});
                fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_ANNOTATION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            xxxLog.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Error:" + e);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            CommonUtilities.showToast(activity, activity.getString(R.string.error_message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
```

After this code chooser opens similar to like this.
[image]

Now how can I add share location icon to this file chooser dialog and after selecting a particular location and share it to other user in chat application?

Comment: You can try this editor for location sharing https://github.com/irshuLx/Android-WYSIWYG-Editor  Or you can go with bottomsheet dialog for same dialog as whatsapp

Comment: @VishvaDave I don't want it from Editor. I want to open it from chooser dialog. And after choosing a location it should be displayed like a last screenshot that i have attached.

Comment: Try this bottomsheet dialog https://medium.com/glucosio-project/moving-from-dialogs-to-bottomsheetdialogs-on-android-15fb8d140295  and use custom layout in recyclerview item for map type... this will be a broad answer start on something and get back when any errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try :**

1. Any chooser don't have every type of actions (i.e video,location,audio,document etc) every chooser is based on one category. So for this chooser screen use **[Bottomsheet dialog](https://medium.com/glucosio-project/moving-from-dialogs-to-bottomsheetdialogs-on-android-15fb8d140295)**. It is same as dialog it will have custom layout. just make one layout same as the screen and inflate in this.
2. Now Inside dialog on click of location open **[place picker](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/placepicker)** of google. It will look same as your location picker screen.
3. For location display use a custom item layout in recyclerview. i.e layout will have linear layout(vertical) -> imageview and two textviews with some padding. **[Recyclerview demo](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)**.

Comment: Can you answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50674829/how-to-display-location-message-in-chat-window-same-like-whatsapp-in-android-pro?